# Explain the unconditional covariance in Dynamic Conditional correlation( DCC ) GARCH model

Tags: garch

Confused about the unconditional covariance matrix in a DCC GARCH model. Could anyone help me understand it? My understanding is that we get the unconditional covariance before based on the data sets. For example, two data sets, A and B, then the unconditional covariance matrix is built by the variance of A and B respectively and covariance of them, is that true? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link to what you are reading about DCC GARCH at the moment?

Comment: Yes, @Richard. [link](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~rengle/Dcc-Sheppard.pdf ). Words to explain the unconditional covariance is on the page 5 under equation (2). Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about the $\overline{Q}$, right?

If so, it is the covariance between the error terms $E_{i,t}$ and $E_{j,t}$.(The sub term $i$ comes from asset $i$, and $j$ for asset $j$)

Comment: Please be straight to the point when answering, it's just clearer for everybody.

Comment: Thanks @SRKX. I understand it now. So one more question, $\bar{Q}$ can be estimated by the standard residuals, so is this matrix is the parameters in the model, i n other words, I want to estimate the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC), and I need to know the number of parameters, I wonder whether the  three parameters in the matrix needs to be considered. If not considered, then there will be 8 parameter in a bivariate case, otherwise, there will be 11 parameters.

Comment: Dear @SRKX, sorry for the previous question, I have already understood the model now. The elements in $\bar{Q}$ should be considered in.